# How can I open a x-window application on a remote machine and make that window shown in my local machine

Tags: linux, ssh, x11

I have a remote server running Linux and I am using macOS. I can connect to that server through `ssh` command. I noticed that `ssh -X` is used to enable X11 forwarding. So I tried to connect to that server by running `ssh -X name@ip-address` command and launched an application on the connection terminal. I expect that window should be shown on my macOS but it didn't. Is there any other configuration I need to set in other to make the X11 forward works?

Comment: you can use mobaxterm app - it has free version; sorry not for MAC, but easiest would be using some tool: http://alternativeto.net/software/mobaxterm/?platform=mac

Comment: Do you run X on your mac?

Comment: Then you had an x-forwarding failure. That is *exactly* how x-forwarding works. You can also try `ssh -Y user@host`, but you need to *enable* `X11-Forwarding` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` by setting `X11Forwarding yes` (then restart `sshd`, on a `systemd` system, `systemctl restart sshd`)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because your question is more properly asked on the StackExchange site [**Unix & Linux**](http://unix.stackexchange.com/). Good luck with your solution.

Comment: Did you see any errors? X11 apps usually show `Can't open display` error in that case.

Comment: @choroba you are right. It works fine after installing XQuartz on mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macs don't run their GUI in X. You need to install XQuartz first.